# How to solve Dispatcher.BeginInvoke error

Tags: vb.net, dispatcher, begininvoke

I have this procedure (converted from C#):

```
Private Sub _biometrics_IdentifyFailed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AuthenticationFailedEventArgs)
    ' See comment above...
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, New Action(Function()
                                                                              StatusTextBox.Text = "Failed"
                                                                              UsernameTextBox.Text = [String].Empty
                                                                              _session.Close()
                                                                              _session = _biometrics.OpenSession()
                                                                          End Function))
End Sub
```

I am having an error in the 'Dispatcher.BegingInvoke' saying 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference'.

I can't seem to figure out what this means or how to solve it.

Can someone understand it and help me solve it?

This is a windows forms application, VS 2010, .NET framework 4.0.

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwhc0d0(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no Dispatcher property available in the current scope.  Since the Dispatcher is also a type, the compiler defaults to attempting to call a *static* `BeginInvoke`method defined on the Dispatcher type.  There is none, there is only an instance method, and that's what the exception is saying.

What you are *really doing* is you are copypasting WPF code snippets into your Windows Forms application.  The **Dispatcher** is used in WPF applications.  This is known as "god tier" application development.  You aren't programming within this heightened sphere.  Because this can be read by children, I'll refrain from describing what Windows Forms development using VB.NET is.

You're probably trying to update the UI from a background thread. In this case, you will be using [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) to update the control from a background thread.  You're probably in the codebehind for a control, so just invoke the method this way:

```
Private Sub _biometrics_IdentifyFailed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AuthenticationFailedEventArgs)
    ' See comment above...
    BeginInvoke(New InvokeDelegate(AddressOf InvokeMethod))
    _session.Close()
    _session = _biometrics.OpenSession()    
end Sub


Public Sub InvokeMethod()
    StatusTextBox.Text = "Failed"
    UsernameTextBox.Text = [String].Empty 
End Sub
```

Note that `_biometrics_IdentifyFailed` is executing on the background thread, so only background work should be happening there.  `InvokeMethod` will execute on the UI thread, so only UI updates should happen there.  I don't VB, so I might have some syntax errors in here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @Will. I took this as an opportunity to find out what wpf is all about. So I have recreated the application in wpf, the procedures are working fine. the `InvokeDelegate` returned the error of not defined in Winform app, so I decided not pursue it further!